# Rewrite Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Compare_List

Tags: module, overrides

I wish to rewrite some methods in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Compare_List`. What do I need to add to config.xml and what should my classname be?

Comment: The class name is technically arbitrary, though if you are following convention then (1) its definition will be autoloaded by the class name, and (2) it will be located in a Block subfolder in your module and therefore the name will begin with `Namespace_ModuleName_Block`.

Comment: So, since the name is `.._Block_Product_Compare_List` I should create a file named `list.php` in `../Namespace/Modulename/Block/Product/Compare/` and put my class there, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create block `Namespace_Modulename_Block_Product_Compare_List` and extend it from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Compare_List`. Rewrite all methods you need.

Then in config.xml

```
<config>
    <global>
        ...
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                   <product_compare_list>Namespace_Modulename_Block_Product_Compare_List</product_compare_list>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
       </blocks>
        ...
    </global>
</config>
```

Anyway [here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/) you can find more information about rewriting in magento.